# KeyError: 'Zoolander'

Tags: python-3.x

Estudio (libro "Mastering Python for Data Science") como generar recomendaciones con un filtrado colaborativo.
Se dispone de un conjunto de usuarios que han otorgado calificaciones a las películas de su elección. Se parte de un diccionario que contiene los diferentes usuarios en forma de claves y sus valores en forma de un diccionario de películas, siendo el valor de cada película la calificación otorgada por un usuario

```
movie_user_preferences={'Jill': {'Avenger: Age of Ultron': 7.0,
                                 'Django Unchained': 6.5,'Gone Girl': 9.0,'Kill the Messenger': 8.0},
                        'Julia': {'Avenger: Age of Ultron': 10.0,'Django Unchained': 6.0,'Gone Girl': 6.5,
                                  'Kill the Messenger': 6.0,'Zoolander': 6.5},
                        'Max': {'Avenger: Age of Ultron': 7.0,'Django Unchained': 7.0,'Gone Girl': 10.0,
                                'Horrible Bosses 2': 6.0,'Kill the Messenger': 5.0,'Zoolander': 10.0},
                        'Robert': {'Avenger: Age of Ultron': 8.0,'Django Unchained': 7.0,'Horrible Bosses 2': 5.0,
                                   'Kill the Messenger': 9.0,'Zoolander': 9.0},
                        'Sam': {'Avenger: Age of Ultron': 10.0,'Django Unchained': 7.5,'Gone Girl': 6.0,
                                'Horrible Bosses 2': 3.0,'Kill the Messenger': 5.5,'Zoolander': 7.0},
                        'Toby': {'Avenger: Age of Ultron': 8.5,'Django Unchained': 9.0,'Zoolander': 2.0},
                        'William': {'Avenger: Age of Ultron': 6.0, 'Django Unchained': 8.0,'Gone Girl': 7.0,
                                    'Horrible Bosses 2': 4.0,'Kill the Messenger': 6.5,'Zoolander': 4.0}}
```

Para generar las recomendaciones se aplica la función:

```
def get_recommendedItems(prefs,itemMatch,user):
    userRatings = prefs[user]
    scores = {}
    totalSim = {}

    # Bucle sobre los elementos clasificados por este usuario
    for (item,rating) in userRatings.items( ):
        # Bucle sobre elementos similares a este
        for (similarity,item2) in itemMatch[item]:
            # Ignorar si este usuario ya ha calificado este artículo.
            if item2 in userRatings: continue
            #  Suma ponderada de la calificación de similitud
            scores.setdefault(item2,0)
            scores[item2] += similarity*rating

            # Suma de todas las similitudes.
            totalSim.setdefault(item2,0)
            totalSim[item2] += similarity

    # Divide cada puntaje total por ponderación total para obtener un promedio
    rankings = [(score/totalSim[item],item) for item,score in scores.items( )]
    # Devuelve los rankings de mayor a menor
    rankings.sort( )
    rankings.reverse( )
    return rankings 

get_recommendedItems(movie_user_preferences, itemsim,'Toby')
```

Me devuelve un error desconocido para mi y que tampoco encuentro tipificado en Internet.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-6cb6af342230> in <module>
----> 1 get_recommendedItems(movie_user_preferences, itemsim,'Toby')

<ipython-input-74-7775b1776c13> in get_recommendedItems(prefs, itemMatch, user)
      7     for (item,rating) in userRatings.items( ):
      8         # Loop over items similar to this one
----> 9         for (similarity,item2) in itemMatch[item]:
     10             # Ignore if this user has already rated this item
     11             if item2 in userRatings: continue

KeyError: 'Zoolander'
```

¿Cual puede ser la causa del error?

Efectivamente, "Zoolander" es una de las claves del dicionario de usuarios que han calificado películas.
Por otro lado, itemsim es un diccinario creado con una función que se ejecuta antes, cuyo objeto es encontrar películas similares para cada una de las películas.
Por alguna razón que aún no he encontrado, en el este diccionario no aparece "Zoolander", y de ahí el error.

Comment: El error es bastante habitual: `KeyError` indica que has intentado acceder a una clave inexistente de un diccionario. En este caso la clave es "Zoolander". Posiblemente la estructura de datos que manejas no es correcta para el algoritmo que intentas aplicar. Por otro lado he intentado replicar el error para darte más detalles, pero no he podido porque falta la inicialización de `itemsim`. ¿Qué contendría esa variable?

Comment: PD: He completado el código con el resto de funciones necesarias tomadas del libro "Mastering Python for Data Science", y lo he ejecutado, y a mi no me aparece ese error, sino el resultado: `[(7.044841200971884, 'Kill the Messenger'), (6.476296577225752, 'Horrible Bosses 2'), (5.0651585538275095, 'Gone Girl')]`